# Regular Expression in Python for (\xa0) and (<a).*(>).*(</a>)

Tags: python, regex

Just reading through some code for pre-processing text data, and came across these regex and am struggling to figure out what they mean.

```
ReviewText = ReviewText.str.replace('(<a).*(>).*(</a>)', '')   
ReviewText = ReviewText.str.replace('(\xa0)', ' ')
```

Comment: What's the string that you do this regex to?

Comment: The first one looks like it wants to remove all *hyperlink* tags from some html.

Comment: @U10-Forward-ReinstateMonica it's applied onto text data (reviews of a product)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, it looks like they are playing with HTML using regexp . . . generally, folks frown on that but given you are using, not developing we'll ignore that issue for now.

Looks like the first line would take:

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
```

and suppress it to nothing.

The second one takes the shown string and changes it to a space.

As the person above stated, you need both the regexp and input to actually do anything with that.  Once you have both the regexp and some input, I recommend playing with the input with a regexp checker . . . like here (or equal): https://pythex.org/